# ANCOVA com teste de homogeneidade das curvas

Tags: regressão

Estou fazendo algumas análises de ANCOVA, porém não sei se eu não estou sabendo interpretar os resultados. Entendo que uma ANCOVA seria uma ANOVA junto com as regressões. Porém eu preciso de um teste homogeneidade das curvas.

AS funções Anova e aov não me retornam esta informação, alguém sabe o que eu poderia fazer. Procurei nas outras perguntas postadas no fórum, mas não encontrei nada resolutivo!

obrigada !

Comment: Depois de pesquisar melhor sobre ANCOVA, é possível faz pelo R sim! Basta realizar uma ANOVA e um teste homogeneidade da inclinação das curvas.